# Every element in a ring can be written as a product of non-units elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to understand a little detail in this proof:

[image]
[image]

I didn't understand why in a ring we can always write an element as a products of non-units elements.

I need help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is what it means that $a$ is NOT irreducible.

Comment: When $a$ is irreducible there is nothing to prove, so let's examine the non-irreducible case. Instead of "so" I'd probably use "otherwise".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question has been answered by the comments.   In the sentence under question, the writer is dealing with the case where $a$ is reducible, so by definition of reducible, $a = bc$ for some nonunits $b$ and $c$.

It is untrue that all ring elements can be expressed as products of nonunits.  The product $a = bc$ is a unit if and only if $b$ and $c$ *are* units.